# Numpy function returning the percentile of a data set a number *would* map to if that value was inserted into that set

Tags: python, numpy

Let say I have a numpy array `data = [1,1.5,4,5]`

I'm looking for a function or the best way to write one that I can input a number and that would output the percentile the number would map to if it were in the data set.

Say `x = 3`

I'm looking for `f(data,x) -> 50`

Answer (score 0):

```
import scipy.stats

data = [1,1.5,4,5]
scipy.stats.percentileofscore(data,3, 'rank')
```

Outputs: `50.0`